# Javascript custom sort algorithm according to another array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have this two arrays

```
var refArray = ['India','Pakistan','Nepal','Bhutan','SreeLanka','Singapore','Thailand','China','Russia']
var beenThere = ['Russia','Bhutan','India']
```

I need to sort `beenThere` on the order of refArray for display purpose, so if I sort `beenThere`, result should be,

```
['India','Bhutan','Russia']
```

Where can I get one algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the data are strings, and the strings don't have commas, you can avoid all user-land iteration with a dynamic RegExp:

```
var refArray = ['India','Pakistan','Nepal','Bhutan','SreeLanka','Singapore','Thailand','China','Russia']
var beenThere = ['Russia','Bhutan','India'];


(","+refArray+",").match(RegExp(",("+beenThere.join("|")+"),","g")).join(",").split(/,+/).slice(1,-1); 
// ==  ["India", "Bhutan", "Russia"]
```

that one is nice in that it doesn't need [].indexOf(), so it works in older browsers. you can use another delimeter besides comma if the data has commas, with some slightly uglier code...

or, using filter for the iteration, but with a native method instead of a user-land function:

```
var refArray = ['India','Pakistan','Nepal','Bhutan','SreeLanka','Singapore','Thailand','China','Russia']
var beenThere = ['Russia','Bhutan','India'];

refArray.filter(/./.test, RegExp("("+beenThere.join("|")+")","g"));
// == ["India", "Bhutan", "Russia"]
```

these would probably perform faster than indexOf(), but sorting is a weird operation, with lots of opportunity for behind-the-scenes optimization, so results may vary.

Answer (score 3):

a faster way is to use the pre-sorted array as a template, and limit the indexOf() work to a single indexOf() call on the sub-set items, instead of 2-indexOf() calls on all items.

```
var refArray = ['India','Pakistan','Nepal','Bhutan','SreeLanka','Singapore','Thailand','China','Russia']
var beenThere = ['Russia','Bhutan','India'];
function contains(a){return this.indexOf(a)!==-1; }
refArray.filter(contains, beenThere); // == ["India", "Bhutan", "Russia"]
```

Comment: "*a faster way **is***"—than what? I think you need to back that up. ;-)

Comment: indexOf() is expensive.  if you run indexOf() on the big array twice per iteration, it does more work and thus takes more time than running one indexOf() on the smaller array each iteration. this will be especially true where indexOf() is polyfilled by user-land code.

Comment: Well, [*testing in various browsers*](http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-indexof) shows filter is slightly faster in Safari, but slower in Firefox and Chrome. Tests with different size arrays may change that. Regardless of theory, it's the implementation that matters. ;-)

Comment: @RobG And it actually makes sense, because filter has to check all the `refArray` items, while with sort+indexOf we need to visit only few items in `beenArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
beenThere.sort(function(a, b) {
    return refArray.indexOf(a) - refArray.indexOf(b); 
}); // ['India','Bhutan','Russia']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just compare the indices of each element in the `refArray` using `indexOf` method.

```
beenThere.sort(function(a,b){
return refArray.indexOf(a)-refArray.indexOf(b);
})
```